# Oracle Sql XE - Error al entrar a sqlplus [Linux deepin (basado en debian)]

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo un problema al intentar logear a sqlplus desde la terminal.

ejecuto el comando sqlplus, y luego me pide usuario y contraseña.

al intentar poner system y la contraseña que puse durante la instalación, me encuentro con el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

INFORMACIÓN:

SISTEMA OPERATIVO: GNU/LINUX DEEPIN

ARQUITECTURA     : 64x

SOFTWARE         : Oracle-xe 11g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error indica que la base de datos no esta disponible, hay que iniciar la base y luego el listener de la misma. Esto ocurre por que el servicio de Oracle no fue configurado para arrancarse en automatico (esto esta bien si no se va a usar la base de datos siempre que se inicia el equipo de computo donde se instalo).

Lo que ha de hacerse es iniciar la base de datos y luego el listener de la misma.

Los comandos siguientes deben hacerse con el usuario de Sistema Operativo **oracle**. Pueden hacerse con cualquier otro usuario del Sistema Operativo pero para no hacer tan larga la respuesta lo haremos solo con el usuario **oracle**.

Antes de ejecutar comandos debes asegurarte que las variables de entorno ORACLE_SID y ORACLE_HOME estan configuradas.

Si no lo estuvieran hay que ejecutar previamente:

```
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/
```

Para comodidad puede agregarse las siguientes variables de entorno para tenerlas en el PATH.

```
export ORACLE_CONFIGURACION=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_CONFIGURACION
```

(nota: las rutas que coloco corresponden a la instalación en mi sistema linux, el cual no es exactamente el mismo que el tuyo, asegúrate que las rutas que coloco son las que corresponden a tu instalación)
Luego de esto para iniciar la base de dato ejecuta:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Eso te debe mostrar una salida como:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sun May 6 00:34:37 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL>
```

Si haz visto lo anterior estas en el prompt del sqlplus. Ahora ejecuta STARTUP para iniciar la base de datos.

```
SQL> STARTUP
```

La salida debe indicar algo como:

```
Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes
Fixed Size          2233344 bytes
Variable Size         624954368 bytes
Database Buffers      436207616 bytes
Redo Buffers            5541888 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

Lo que sigue es iniciar el listener de la base (puede entenderse como el servicio que escucha las conexiones). Para ello hay que salir del prompt del sqlplus escribiendo quit

```
SQL> quit
```

Eso te mostrará una salida como la siguiente

```
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Ahora desde la terminal escribimos: `lsnrctl start`

Esto arrojará una salida como la siguiente:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-MAY-2018 00:41:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                06-MAY-2018 00:41:38
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Luego ya puedes conectarte a la base de datos via sqlplus con el usuario que comentas

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sun May 6 00:49:29 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system
Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

Solo comentar que estos pasos funcionan tanto para una base de datos 11g XE como para un Oracle 12c variando únicamente los paths de las variables de entorno.

Quedo atento a cualquier comentario o duda.

Comment: Excelente!! , problema resuelto. Era justamente lo que tú decias.

Comment: Que bueno que te ayudo. Te pido entonces que marques la respuesta como "aceptada" así la gente que tenga el mismo problema y pase por aquí tendrá confianza en que los pasos comentados le funcionen.

Comment: gracias por tu explicación. Tengo un error al iniciar sqlplus, no me permite introducir la contraseña desde oracle 11g..Gracias de antemano

Comment: @LuisEnriqueGoce para esto que comentas sería mejor generar una nueva pregunta. De esa manera es más fácil que la comunidad la vea y te demos una mejor respuesta.